# Unable to add Event Participants backend

Tags: civievent, profile, registration

I am trying to add event participants back end through Events->Register Event participants. I am getting this error,

"Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type." Civicrm version 4.6.8.

There are two profile fields configured in the event with fields of type 'individual' and 'contact'.

Any help can be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share more information on the fields you are using? E.g. post a screenshot of the profile?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds familiar, I recall some issues similar to what you are reporting (i.e. that message coming up in a misleading way).

I'd try upgrading to a more recent 4.6.x to see if that fixes it (you're going to want to do that for security reasons in any case). The 4.6.x series is reasonably stable, there isn't usually any reason not to upgrade.